# How to start mage guild second quest

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In ESO, you have a rather interesting (at least till now) series of quests for the mage guild (as in all other elder scrolls games actually).

My problem is the following:

- I joined the guild and made the first quest (found the book, talked to shalidor, went to cheesmongors hollow, beat gutsripper and took 1 book).
- Now the guildmaster has to translate it, but it took a while already, made about 10 levels (i'm 15 now), and the second quest still doesn't start. For fighters guild for example, a guy fund me in town and told me to go to guild for further instructions. Also I already leveled up at mage guild tree by finding lore books.

So... do I have to do anything? Or quest will eventually start?

Note: Pls. no spoilers if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throughout the Mages Guid quest-line, you will need to approach a Mages Guild hall in any city once you are in the correct level range for the next quest to start. Arch-Mage Shalidor will appear outside the building, and tell you to go find Valaste. When he does, it will start the next quest, with the first objective being to talk to her.

Comment: Yup, I got the quest like 2 minutes after I made the post :)). Happened the way you described it.